# Nuxt.js middleware redirect based on role

Tags: vue.js, authentication, authorization, nuxt.js, middleware

On login I want to redirect to different page based on role using the nuxt.js middleware.

This is my notAuthenticated middleware

```
export default function({ store, redirect }) {
  // If the user is authenticated redirect to home page
  if (store.state.auth) {
    debugger
    if (store.state.auth.role === 'admin') {
      return redirect('/admin')
    } else {
      return redirect('/')
    }
  }
}
```

Problem is it does not redirect to `/admin` and I don't know how to debug it. Debugger is not working here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems middleware didn't redirect me after login, so I had to use the router and redirect based on the role after the login has completed.

EDIT: As asked I'm adding also the code solution.

In my `login` function, after logging in I check the role of the user (which in my case was saved in the JWT token).

```js
login(data) {
      const self = this
      this.$axios.post('/auth/login', data).then(function(response) {
        const tkData = self.parseJwt(response.data.Token)
        const auth = {
          accessToken: response.data.Token,
          email: tkData.email,
          role: tkData.role
        }
        self.$store.commit('setAuth', auth)
        Cookie.set('auth', auth)
        if (tkData.role === 'admin') {
          self.$router.push('/admin')
        } else {
          self.$router.push('/')
        }
      })
    }
```

PS: You can check out my code and test it in my [GitHub](https://github.com/victor-timofei/board-games-client)

Comment: @flakerimi just added a code snippet, hope it helps :)